# Update MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY oracle spatial

Tags: sql, oracle, геолокация, spatial, geoserver

У меня есть таблица где есть колонка `sdo_geometry` например у меня есть два строка которые оделно нарисуют одну полигон, как мне обнавит один из них чтоби этот показал сразу две полигони

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 32638, null, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), 
MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(490738.20, 4542270.10, 490839, 4542278.50, 
491065.80, 4542261.70, 491177.80, 4542194.50, 491228.20, 4542062.90, 
491259, 4541964.90, 491060.20, 4541816.50, 491121.80, 
4541617.70, 491376.60, 4541668.10, 491511, 4541592.50, 491698.60, 
4541648.50, 491877.80, 4541631.70, 491788.20, 4541525.30, 491768.60, 
4541460.90, 491620.20, 4541368.50, 491477.40, 4541301.30, 491485.80, 
4541220.10, 491513.80, 4541071.70, 491455, 4541063.30, 491225.40, 4541091.30, 
491023.80, 4541393.70, 490923, 4541466.50, 490746.60, 4541553.30, 490671, 
4541620.50, 490797, 4541816.50, 490965, 4542093.70, 490685, 4542079.70, 490738.20, 4542270.10))
```

---

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 32638, null, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(504027, 4529381.80, 504052.20, 4529297.80, 503965.40, 4529222.20, 503867.40, 4529292.20, 503901, 4529409.80, 503951.40, 4529471.40, 504027, 4529381.80))
```